# How to wait for the retrofit call response

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-room

I have my own rest api for application so when I create post request to api I want to wait for the response and then do something. how I can wait for the call response.

insert TicketList

```
public long insertApi(TicketListTable ticketListTable) throws IOException {
        Call<TicketListTable> ticketListTableCall = dataService.createTicketList(ticketListTable);
        
        ticketListTableCall.enqueue(new Callback<TicketListTable>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TicketListTable> call, Response<TicketListTable> response) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TicketListTable> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
        // want to wait for the call to complete then return the value
        //ticketListTableCall.execute();
        Log.d("CODE", "insertApi: "+ ticketListTableCall.isExecuted());
        return repo.insert(ticketListTable);
    }
```

this method is called when button is clicked

```
 public void saveListToDb(String[] split, String regexData){
        String newListName = listName.getText().toString();
        SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        TicketListTable newTicketListTable = new TicketListTable();
        newTicketListTable.setTicketListName(newListName);

        newTicketListTable.setTicketListCreated(sd.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
        newTicketListTable.setTicketListUpdated(sd.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));

        long ticketTableListId = 0;
        try {
            ticketTableListId = ticketTableVm.insert(newTicketListTable);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(ticketTableListId<=0){
            throw new ArithmeticException();
        }
        for (String s : split) {
            String[] values = s.split(regexData);
            String number = values[0].replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
            String info = values[1];
            String warningNote = values[2];
            String warning = values[3];
            String customer = values[4];
            int useable = Integer.parseInt(values[5].replaceAll("\\s+", "").replace("\n", "").replace("\r", ""));
            TicketTable ticketTable = new TicketTable(number, customer, info, warningNote, useable, ticketTableListId,warning);
            ticketTableVm.insert(ticketTable);
        }
    }
```

insert Ticket api call, before calling this I want to verify that the previous call has been successfully executed

```
public void insert(TicketTable ticketTable) throws IOException {
        Call<TicketTable> ticketCall = dataService.createTicket(ticketTable);
        //Response resp =  ticketCall.execute();
        ticketCall.enqueue(new Callback<TicketTable>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TicketTable> call, Response<TicketTable> response) {
                repo.insert(ticketTable);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TicketTable> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: is `onResponse` not what you are looking for ? That is a callback method. Also post all necessary code

Comment: i tried that, while ticketList is being created in db, there are other calls to create ticket which has foreign key to ticketList. As specific ticketList doesnt exist yet in api then the other insertion fails.

Comment: `onResponse` is the only place you'll be able to access the data

Comment: I am guessing your POST request would give you back a status code. So in `onResonse`, 
`Response` would give you the status code. Use `response.code()` to get the response code. And always check if the response was successful